# How to get the trading price and commission in Interactive Brokers (IBPY) after placing an order?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy

http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/ maybe a useful link. 
[This picture is from java API guide of Interacitve Brokers and the numbers I want are price and commission in trade log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQVWl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.ext.CommissionReport import CommissionReport
from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt
```

Make functions to handle each type of callback you're interested in.

```
def error_handler(msg):
    print (msg)

def execDetails(msg):
    print('ID',msg.execution.m_execId,'PRICE',msg.execution.m_price)

def commReport(msg):
    print('ID',msg.commissionReport.m_execId,'COM',msg.commissionReport.m_commission)

tws = Connection.create(port = 4001, clientId=123)
tws.register(execDetails, message.execDetails)
tws.register(commReport, message.commissionReport)
tws.register(error_handler, 'Error')
tws.connect()
```

You should wait for `connect()` to finish, I usually just use the nextOrderId callback to notify me when ready but in python you could sleep(2) or in this case I'm using the notebook so I just run the next cells later.

```
fx = Contract()
fx.m_secType = "CASH" 
fx.m_symbol = "USD"
fx.m_currency = "CAD"
fx.m_exchange = "IDEALPRO"
#tws.reqMktData(1,fx,"",False)

ord = Order()
ord.m_orderType = 'MKT'
ord.m_totalQuantity = 100000
ord.m_action = 'SELL'
tws.placeOrder(123,fx,ord) #increment this every order
```

This prints

```
ID 0001f4e8.57427bd9.01.01 PRICE 1.31565
ID 0001f4e8.57427bd9.01.01 COM 2.6313`
```

Don't forget `tws.disconnect()` at some point

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code perfectly solve my question.