# How to get the trading price and commission in Interactive Brokers new API (9.73) after placing an order?

Tags: interactive-brokers

I'm looking at ib_insync, framework for new Interactive Brokers python API. One thing I can't figure out is how to get the trading price after placing market order. Has anyone figured it out?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382451/how-to-get-the-trading-price-and-commission-in-interactive-brokers-ibpy-after/37391696#37391696), but it's for the old API and IBPY.

Comment: There is a user group for that unofficial framework here https://groups.io/g/insync/topics

Answer (score 2):

If anyone wants to know, here's how to get the price at which you bought/sold:

```
from ib_insync.order import MarketOrder    
order = MarketOrder(action, quantity)
trade = self.ib.placeOrder(contract, order)
# Wait for the trade to complete
...
filled_quantity = trade.filled()
filled_price = trade.orderStatus.avgFillPrice
```

Comment: Does this include the trading fee's & Commissions ?